# Firebase Analytics (ARPPU) has stopped attributing IAP to users

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

We have had this app on Firebase for over a year, and it just recently stop tracking IAPs properly.

The problem is, our ARPPU is the same value as our IAP totals from both stores. It's as if Firebase thinks the same user is making all the purchases. It's also happening to historical data as well. It doesn't matter how far back we look, the ARPPU is always the same as the total purchases. This was not always the case, it was working fine a few months ago.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I have the same issue.  Are you using subscriptions?  Are you using Unity?  Are you on Android and iOS?  (I am.)

Comment: We are using subscriptions in one of our apps (which is in beta/soft launch) and we just noticed that it's also happening in that app as well.

Comment: We have the same issue without subscriptions (using Unity & Android). Do you figure out anything?

Comment: Hey any progress on that? I'm using Firebase for a few months in a mobile game (Android & iOS) and recently I started to have some revenue and I see the same behavior - ARPPU is equal to the sum of all revenues from purchases shown for a selected period.
Here's a screenshot of what it shows:
https://imgur.com/a/w33R6Cp

Comment: Sorry! Nothing has changed for us.